# ASP.NET v4.0 Classic App Pool Crashing

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

I am running IIS 7.5 with Windows Server 2008 RT (on Windows 7) and our ASP.Net app keeps crashing unexpectedly.  I setup a rule with DebugDiag 2 and can't seem to pinpoint what exactly is causing the worker threads to crash.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Below is the dump log:

```
 Loading control script C:\Program Files\DebugDiag\scripts\CrashRule_WebAppPool_ASP.NET v4.0 Classic.vbs
DumpPath set to C:\Program Files\DebugDiag\Logs\Crash rule for IIS web application pool - ASP.NET v4.0 Classic
[3/9/2016 1:23:12 PM]
  Process created. BaseModule - c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe. BaseThread System ID - System ID: 4292
  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll loaded at 0x77460000
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 2984
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 3916
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 4436
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 3596
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 4076
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 4624
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 2664
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 2808
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 2760
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 784
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 1168
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 2612
  C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll loaded at 0x76d60000
  C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll loaded at 0xfdc20000
  C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll loaded at 0xff440000
  C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll loaded at 0xfdcb0000
  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll loaded at 0xfdc90000
  C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll loaded at 0xff5a0000
  C:\Windows\system32\pcwum.DLL loaded at 0xfcb90000
  C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll loaded at 0x77200000
  C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll loaded at 0xff090000
  C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll loaded at 0xff080000
  C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll loaded at 0xfeeb0000
  C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll loaded at 0xff230000
  c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\IISUTIL.dll loaded at 0xfaa90000
  C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL loaded at 0xfee80000
  C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll loaded at 0xff120000
  C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll loaded at 0xfd7b0000
  C:\Windows\system32\ntmarta.dll loaded at 0xfc9d0000
  C:\Windows\system32\WLDAP32.dll loaded at 0xff020000
  c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wphost.dll loaded at 0xfc110000
  C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll loaded at 0xfdd50000
  c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\nativerd.dll loaded at 0xfa930000
  C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll loaded at 0xfda10000
  C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll loaded at 0xfd960000
  C:\Windows\system32\XmlLite.dll loaded at 0xfb530000
  C:\Windows\system32\ktmw32.dll loaded at 0xfbc30000
  c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\IISRES.DLL loaded at 0x74c80000
  C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll loaded at 0xfd150000
  C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll loaded at 0xfce50000
  C:\Windows\system32\mscoree.dll loaded at 0xfabe0000
  C:\Windows\system32\CLBCatQ.DLL loaded at 0xfef80000
  C:\Windows\system32\mlang.dll loaded at 0xf9c30000
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\webengine4.dll loaded at 0xed870000
  C:\Windows\system32\MSVCR120_CLR0400.dll loaded at 0xf20b0000
  C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll loaded at 0xfcbf0000
  C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll loaded at 0xfd8c0000
  C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL loaded at 0x77630000
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll loaded at 0xfaae0000
  C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll loaded at 0xfde30000
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll loaded at 0xf9dd0000
  C:\Windows\system32\MSVCR110_CLR0400.dll loaded at 0xf9cf0000
  C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\iiscore.dll loaded at 0xfc0a0000
  c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\W3TP.dll loaded at 0xf3980000
  c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3dt.dll loaded at 0xfc190000
  C:\Windows\system32\HTTPAPI.dll loaded at 0xf3400000
  C:\Windows\system32\slc.dll loaded at 0xfc050000
  C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll loaded at 0xfdeb0000
  C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll loaded at 0xfdf00000
  C:\Windows\system32\Normaliz.dll loaded at 0x77620000
  C:\Windows\system32\faultrep.dll loaded at 0xfbb50000
  C:\Windows\system32\Secur32.dll loaded at 0xfd6f0000
  C:\Windows\system32\SSPICLI.DLL loaded at 0xfd720000
  C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll loaded at 0xfc200000
  C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll loaded at 0xf9c70000
  C:\Windows\System32\mswsock.dll loaded at 0xfd0f0000
  C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll loaded at 0xfcf70000
  C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll loaded at 0xf9ca0000
  C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll loaded at 0xfcad0000
  C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll loaded at 0xfd0e0000
  C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL loaded at 0xfb470000
  C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL loaded at 0xfb460000
  C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll loaded at 0xfae40000
  C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll loaded at 0xfb2e0000
  C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\cachuri.dll loaded at 0xfc180000
  C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\cachfile.dll loaded at 0xfc100000
  C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\cachtokn.dll loaded at 0xfc090000
  C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\cachhttp.dll loaded at 0xfc070000
  C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\compstat.dll loaded at 0xfbd10000
  C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\defdoc.dll loaded at 0xfbd00000
  C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\dirlist.dll loaded at 0xfbce0000
  C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\protsup.dll loaded at 0xfbcf0000
  C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\static.dll loaded at 0xfbca0000
  C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\authanon.dll loaded at 0xfbcb0000
  C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\authsspi.dll loaded at 0xfbc70000
  C:\Windows\system32\NETAPI32.dll loaded at 0xfb0f0000
  C:\Windows\system32\netutils.dll loaded at 0xfcd80000
  C:\Windows\system32\srvcli.dll loaded at 0xfd650000
  C:\Windows\system32\wkscli.dll loaded at 0xfb0d0000
  C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\modrqflt.dll loaded at 0xfbc60000
  C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\custerr.dll loaded at 0xfbc20000
  C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\loghttp.dll loaded at 0xfbc10000
  C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\iisreqs.dll loaded at 0xfbb40000
  C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll loaded at 0xfba20000
  C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\isapi.dll loaded at 0xfbb10000
  C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\filter.dll loaded at 0xfbaf0000
  C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\validcfg.dll loaded at 0xfbae0000
  C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\rewrite.dll loaded at 0xfba70000
  C:\Program Files\IIS\Application Request Routing\requestRouter.dll loaded at 0xf1f90000
  C:\Windows\system32\WINHTTP.dll loaded at 0xf51e0000
  C:\Windows\system32\webio.dll loaded at 0xf5170000
  C:\Windows\system32\pdh.dll loaded at 0xf1d90000
  C:\Program Files\IIS\Application Request Routing\gzip.dll loaded at 0xfba50000
  C:\Windows\system32\credssp.dll loaded at 0xfcd50000
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_filter.dll loaded at 0xf2190000
  C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll loaded at 0xfba30000
  C:\Windows\system32\schannel.DLL loaded at 0xfcee0000
  C:\Windows\system32\ncrypt.dll loaded at 0xfd2d0000
  C:\Windows\system32\bcrypt.dll loaded at 0xfd2a0000
  C:\Windows\system32\bcryptprimitives.dll loaded at 0xfcd90000
  C:\Windows\system32\GPAPI.dll loaded at 0xfcbd0000
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 4908
  Initializing control script
  Clearing any existing breakpoints

  Current Breakpoint List(BL)
[3/9/2016 1:23:13 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 4908. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 1:23:14 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 3248
[3/9/2016 1:24:20 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 2612. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 1:25:31 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 3524
[3/9/2016 1:26:48 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 3524. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 1:28:43 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 1168. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 1:28:54 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 1908
[3/9/2016 1:32:37 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 3596. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 1:33:17 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 3260
[3/9/2016 1:34:37 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 1908. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 1:35:15 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 4820
[3/9/2016 1:36:22 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 3260. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 1:36:30 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 720
[3/9/2016 1:38:37 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 3916. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 1:39:49 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 2160
[3/9/2016 1:41:52 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 2160. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 1:42:34 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 3440
[3/9/2016 1:43:55 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 4820. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 1:44:14 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 4488
[3/9/2016 1:45:21 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 3440. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 1:46:30 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 2460
[3/9/2016 1:47:37 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 720. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 1:47:39 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 4200
[3/9/2016 1:48:46 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 2460. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 1:49:40 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 2304
[3/9/2016 1:50:47 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 4200. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 1:50:50 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 2140
[3/9/2016 1:52:37 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 4488. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 1:53:30 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 4840
[3/9/2016 1:54:37 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 2140. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 1:55:07 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 4028
[3/9/2016 1:57:05 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 4840. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 1:57:14 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 3636
[3/9/2016 1:57:30 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 3684
[3/9/2016 1:58:37 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 3636. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 1:58:45 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 716
[3/9/2016 1:59:52 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 3684. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 2:03:34 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 4028. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 2:03:38 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 3108
[3/9/2016 2:04:45 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 716. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 2:05:03 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 4888
[3/9/2016 2:06:30 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 4972
[3/9/2016 2:07:37 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 3108. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 2:08:55 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 4972. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 2:09:37 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 716
[3/9/2016 2:10:44 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 4888. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 2:10:48 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 4412
[3/9/2016 2:11:55 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 716. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 2:12:30 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 2248
[3/9/2016 2:13:37 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 4412. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 2:13:45 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 3268
[3/9/2016 2:14:52 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 2248. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 2:15:00 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 4016
[3/9/2016 2:17:37 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 2304. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 2:18:38 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 3432
[3/9/2016 2:20:22 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 4016. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 2:20:48 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 2608
[3/9/2016 2:25:20 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 3432. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 2:25:30 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 3612
[3/9/2016 2:27:08 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 2608. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 2:27:13 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 3136
[3/9/2016 2:28:52 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 3136. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 2:28:59 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 4812
[3/9/2016 2:32:38 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 2460
[3/9/2016 2:33:45 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 4812. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 2:36:17 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 2460. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 2:36:30 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 4216
[3/9/2016 2:37:58 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 3268. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 2:38:34 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 3440
[3/9/2016 2:39:47 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 3440. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 2:39:57 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 4780
[3/9/2016 2:41:04 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 4216. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 2:41:05 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 4488
[3/9/2016 2:42:57 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 3268
[3/9/2016 2:44:04 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 4488. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 2:45:09 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 3268. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 2:45:28 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 4312
[3/9/2016 2:48:37 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 4780. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 2:49:48 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 3240
[3/9/2016 2:51:30 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 4152
[3/9/2016 2:52:37 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 3240. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 2:53:44 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 4152. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 2:54:54 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 1208
[3/9/2016 2:57:07 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 3612. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 2:57:30 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 4580
[3/9/2016 2:58:37 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 1208. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 2:58:46 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 2016
[3/9/2016 3:01:35 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 3200
[3/9/2016 3:02:42 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 2016. Exit code - 0x00000000
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 4580. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 3:02:50 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 4328
[3/9/2016 3:04:53 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 4312. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 3:05:08 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 4744
[3/9/2016 3:08:37 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 784. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 3:08:50 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 2540
[3/9/2016 3:10:30 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 3200. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 3:10:45 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 4408
[3/9/2016 3:12:37 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 4408. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 3:12:59 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 5104
[3/9/2016 3:14:07 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 4744. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 3:14:18 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 3748
[3/9/2016 3:15:25 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 5104. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 3:15:47 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 1288
[3/9/2016 3:16:54 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 3748. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 3:17:23 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 2476
[3/9/2016 3:18:30 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 1288. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 3:20:12 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 2640
[3/9/2016 3:22:37 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 2476. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 3:23:00 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 5084
[3/9/2016 3:24:17 PM]
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 5084. Exit code - 0x00000000
[3/9/2016 3:24:55 PM]
  Thread created. New thread system id - System ID: 4092
[3/9/2016 3:25:39 PM]
  Exception 0XC0000005 on thread 2540.   DetailID = 1
[3/9/2016 3:25:41 PM]
  Second chance exception - 0XC0000005 caused by thread with System ID: 2540
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 4092. Exit code - 0xffffffff
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 2808. Exit code - 0xffffffff
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 2984. Exit code - 0xffffffff
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 3248. Exit code - 0xffffffff
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 4624. Exit code - 0xffffffff
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 4328. Exit code - 0xffffffff
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 4436. Exit code - 0xffffffff
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 2760. Exit code - 0xffffffff
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 2664. Exit code - 0xffffffff
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 4076. Exit code - 0xffffffff
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 2640. Exit code - 0xffffffff
  Thread exited. Exiting thread system id - System ID: 4292. Exit code - 0xffffffff
  Process exited. Exit code - 0xffffffff

***********************
*  EXCEPTION DETAILS  *
***********************

DetailID = 1
    Count:    1
    Exception #:  0XC0000005
    Stack:        
        IISUTIL!STRU::QueryStr
        iiscore
        requestRouter!RegisterModule
        requestRouter!RegisterModule
        requestRouter!RegisterModule
        requestRouter!RegisterModule
        WINHTTP!WinHttpConnect
        WINHTTP!WinHttpConnect
        WINHTTP!WinHttpConnect
        WINHTTP!WinHttpCreateUrl
        WINHTTP!WinHttpGetDefaultProxyConfiguration
        WINHTTP!WinHttpGetDefaultProxyConfiguration
        WINHTTP
        ntdll!TpReleaseWork
        ntdll!RtlRealSuccessor
        kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk
        ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart






***********************
*  EXCEPTION SUMMARY  *
***********************

    |--------------------|
    | Count | Exception  |
    |--------------------|
    | 1     | 0XC0000005 |
    |--------------------|

Debugging Overhead Cost:
    Total Elapsed Ticks = 7349129 (100%)
    Total Ticks Spent in Debugger Engine = 2401 (0%)
    Total Ticks Spent in Crash Rule Script = 760 (0%)
```

I wasn't sure how to get the analysis summary on here, so I'll post some screen shots.  If more screen shots are needed, I can post those as well!

[image]

This is the first thread that showed an issue:

[image]

Here's the HTTP Report (I had to edit out some of the information):

[image]
[image]

```
Exception Information

IISUTIL!STRU::QUERYSTRIn w3wp__ASP.NET v4.0 Classic__PID__3824__Date__03_09_2016__Time_03_25_39PM__654__Second_Chance_Exception_C0000005.dmp the assembly instruction at iisutil!STRU::QueryStr in c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\iisutil.dll from Microsoft Corporation has caused an access violation exception (0xC0000005) when trying to read from memory location 0x00000000 on thread 10
```

[image]

Thanks again!

Comment: in a very quick look, its seams that some one send to your page huge amount of post data and crash it...

Comment: Thank you, @Aristos.  I'm a beginner at reading these logs, could you direct me to where the size of the data we are receiving would be the issue?

Comment: Look here `iisutil!STRU::QueryStr` is crash, because of huge data, or non ending string probably. So locate the page that receive that post (its says that is post data), and see what and from what ip this is post. Also maybe its a bug of your program that is make some dead loop to the same page ? I don't know... find the page that is causing this for start